# List of questions that cause to get Inquisitive badge

Tags: discussion, badges

Today I get Inquisitive badge that awarded when `Asked a well-received question on 30 separate days, and maintained a positive question record`. I want to know list of questions that cause me to get this badge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply go to your profile, click on questions, and sort by votes.

https://stackoverflow.com/users/1407421/mehdi-lotfi?tab=questions&sort=votes

Yes, it's possible that the top ~30 won't be the exact 30 that got you the badge, but it is pretty effective. And should be correct as long as you don't have any negative scored questions/closed questions on the same day as any of those 30 questions.

---

Running this query https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/202534/asking-over-time-badges should give you the number questions you have that currently count towards that badge category.