# Why is the edit button disabled for non-wiki questions and answers on Meta?

Tags: support, edits

The edit button for other user's non-wiki questions and answers is disabled on Meta. I don't understand why. For example the edit button of [this Meta answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/262402/1407421) is disabled for me.

Why is this so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot suggest edits to regular posts on per-site Metas. Until you reach 2,000 reputation (gaining you full editing privileges) on the main site, you won't be able to edit anything here.